# Someone can explain me why $\tan(-\frac{\pi}4+\arctan x)=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Someone can explain me why $tan(-\frac{\pi}4+\arctan x)=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$??

I try to understand it, bot I don't understand how to came from one side to the other...

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the addition formula for $\tan$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I don't think so...

Comment: $$\tan(a\pm b) = \frac{\tan(a)\pm\tan(b)}{1\mp\tan(a)\tan(b)}.$$

Comment: Thank you!!! Both of you help me a lot!!

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that
$$\tan(a-b)=\dfrac{\tan a-\tan b}{1+\tan a\tan b}$$
So, let $b=\pi/4,a=\arctan x$. Then,
$$\tan(\arctan x-\pi/4)=\dfrac{\tan \arctan x-\tan \pi/4}{1+\tan \arctan x\tan \pi/4}=\dfrac{x-1}{1+x}$$